# Chemfig: how to make a vertical dashed line in the center of the bond

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I'm doing presentation about red-ox reactions in beamer, and I need to make a dashed line like on the photo[image]

\chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(=[:35]O)-[:-35]O-H}

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Please show the code you have so far ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setcharge{extra sep=6pt, macro charge=\footnotesize}
\chemfig{
    \charge{90=I}{H}
    -C(-[2]\charge{90=I}{H})(-[6]\charge{-90=I}{H})
    -[@{cc}]C(=[:35]\charge{90=\llap{$-$}II}{O})
    -[:-35]\charge{-90=\llap{$-$}II}{O}
    -\charge{90=I}{H}
    }
\chemmove{
    \draw[-,dashed] ([yshift=2pt]cc) -- ++(0,2);
    \draw[-,dashed] ([yshift=-2pt]cc) -- ++(0,-2);
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much and I have one question is on the internet any guide how to make these chemmoves ?

Comment: Yes, TikZ manual.